# In jQuery, how does the this.each() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

To make my question more specific, I read the documentation on .each() for jQuery, but I am a little more confused.  I have this code:

```
$.fn.imgAreaSelect = function (options) {
options = options || {};

this.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('imgAreaSelect')) {
        if (options.remove) {
            $(this).data('imgAreaSelect').remove();
            $(this).removeData('imgAreaSelect');
        }
        else
            $(this).data('imgAreaSelect').setOptions(options);
    }
    else if (!options.remove) {
        if (options.enable === undefined && options.disable === undefined)
            options.enable = true;

        $(this).data('imgAreaSelect', new $.imgAreaSelect(this, options));
    }
});

if (options.instance)
    return $(this).data('imgAreaSelect');

return this;
```

};

Now what I don't get about this is that why does the each function not have an index or an element?  This snippet of code is from a jQuery plugin that I was trying to read over.  I also don't quite understand the $.fn. at the top, i know it stands for prototype, but what's exactly going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The each function can take a function accepting an index as a parameter, but it's optional.

For simplicity's sake, `.each` was implemented to have `this` refer to the current element.

However, `.each` *can* accept an index as a parameter to it's callback.

There's an example of that usage in the jQuery API

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Reference
- http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: But look at the third line of code: `this.each(function() {`. On that line specifically, what is `this.each(` doing? I'm skeptical that it's the same since we don't see `this` being wrapped as a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need an index, since `this` provides the context.  As noted by the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), "The value can also be accessed through the this keyword."  This is accomplished by using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call).  Something like:

```
userFunction.call(valueOfElement, indexInArray, valueOfElement);
```

`$.fn.imgAreaSelect = function (options)` means the function is being added to the prototype.  This allows it to be used with any instance of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

`$.each(fn)` calls `fn` for each element contained in the current context. Each time it calls `fn`, it passes the "current" element as `this`.

So in the following example:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    alert(this.className);
});
```

Will pop up one alert for each `<div>` in the DOM, and display the class name of each.